# How to convert cardinal numbers to ordinal numbers in postgres I am need this for cleaning street addresses?

Tags: postgresql, gis, street-address, ordinal, cardinality

I have Street addresses like

First Avenue,
Second Drive,
Third Street,
Fourth Road,
Fifth Xing,

I need to convert them into

1st Avenue,
2nd Drive,
3rd Street,
4th Road,
5th Xing

is there a query exist that convert these cardinal numbers to ordinal numbers?

Comment: Warning: you should check the context. Sometime you can have names which are the identical to cardinal names, and that should never be abbreviated. But for consistency/equality check, you should not normalize names (also street names). Good writing style is to use the preferred way, never to "normalize".

Comment: I will take care of all context do you have any solution for my problem.